# PCF Dev RabbitMQ Management Dashboard not installed

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

On a fresh install of PCF Dev, after logging in:

> cf create-service p-rabbitmq standard my_rabbitmq

```
Showing info of service my_rabbitmq in org system / space system as admin...

name:            my_rabbitmq
service:         p-rabbitmq
bound apps:
tags:
plan:            standard
description:     RabbitMQ is a robust and scalable high-performance multi-protocol messaging broker.
documentation:
dashboard:       https://rabbitmq-management.local.pcfdev.io/#/login/mu-3ea7453d-7cff-44bd-b7a7-ce0290d9b4d6-v509qlipcuhnu6relaeuat49ca/25849257198976921347999121731293969259

Showing status of last operation from service my_rabbitmq...

status:    create succeeded
message:
started:   2018-01-05T01:48:17Z
updated:   2018-01-05T01:48:17Z
```

When I go to the management dashboard url, the browser displays the following error:

> 404 Not Found: Requested route ('rabbitmq-management.local.pcfdev.io')
>   does not exist.

How can I get the RabbitMQ Management Dashboard to be installed and respond?

Comment: Can you dns lookup on `'rabbitmq-management.local.pcfdev.io`? My guess is no. Your workstation is not able to resolve it.

Comment: Try going to the dashboard link, through the apps manager.

Comment: Incorrect. The domain is resolving normally.

Comment: Hi, did you think about rabbitmq plugins, it seem, that rabbitmq_management plugin was not installed ?

Answer (score 0):

The only fix I found was installing an earlier version of PCF Dev. This solved the issue.

For more details check this thread on [Github](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pcfdev/issues/277).